# How to display S3 object url on white background instead of the default black

Tags: amazon-s3

I have images hosted on S3 that contain transparent elements. There are some cases when the image will be viewed directly by the S3 object url, the problem here is the S3 default background is black so the transparent element turns black.

Is it possible to to set this background to white? here is an example of a link that I would need to show with a white background https://account-sockclub-com.s3.amazonaws.com/vVDZaeX29YbyEjJeD9RvicHw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "S3 default background."  S3 doesn't interact at that level.

You're looking at the Google Chrome default background, or that of another browser if Chrome isn't what you're viewing.  I say that with a reasonable level of confidence, because not only do I find the image unreadable in Chrome, but a cross-check confirms that Firefox and Edge display the image much more like you probably expect -- the text is easily readable in both browsers.  This image would look exactly the same in each web browser if you were using a web server other than Amazon S3.